# substring index range

Tags: java, string, substring

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "University";
        System.out.println(str.substring(4, 7));
    }   
}
```

**Output:** `ers`

I do not really understand how the substring method works. Does the index start at 0? If I start with 0, `e` is at index 4 but char `i` is at 7 so the output would be `ersi`.

Comment: Also, If you put the begin index as str.length(), It won't throw an IndexOutofBounds excetion. It'll just return an empty string.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

0: U

1: n

2: i

3: v

**4: e**

**5: r**

**6: s**

7: i

8: t

9: y

Start index is inclusive

End index is exclusive

[Javadoc link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what I found informative; beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive. endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.

Comment: Just think of it as a char array with base 0 as all other arrays, and that the second argument is the *stop* position rather than the end position.

Answer (score 14):

Both are 0-based, but the start is inclusive and the end is exclusive. This ensures the resulting string is of length `start - end`.

To make life easier for `substring` operation, imagine that characters are *between* indexes.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  <- available indexes for substring 
 u n i v E R S i t y
        ↑     ↑
      start  end --> range of "E R S"
```

Quoting the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%2c%20int%29):

> The substring begins at the specified
>   `beginIndex` and extends to the
>   character at index `endIndex - 1`. Thus
>   the length of the substring is
>   `endIndex-beginIndex`.

Answer (score 8):

See [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29). It's an inclusive index for the first argument and exclusive for the second.

Answer (score 4):

Like you I didn't find it came naturally. I normally still have to remind myself that

- the *length* of the returned string is

  lastIndex - firstIndex
- that you can use the length of the string as the lastIndex even though there is no character there and trying to reference it would throw an Exception

so

```
"University".substring(6, 10)
```

returns the 4-character string "`sity"` even though there is no character at position 10.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

`beginIndex`—the begin index, inclusive.

`endIndex`—the end index, exclusive.

Example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String Str = new String("Hello World");

        System.out.println(Str.substring(3, 8));
    }
 }
```

Output: "lo Wo"

From 3 to 7 index.

Also there is another kind of `substring()` method:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
```

`beginIndex`—the begin index, inclusive.
Returns a sub string starting from `beginIndex` to the end of the main String.

Example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String Str = new String("Hello World");

        System.out.println(Str.substring(3));
    }
}
```

Output: "lo World"

From 3 to the last index.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the index starts at zero (0). The two arguments are startIndex and endIndex, where per the documentation:

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The substring starts at, and includes the character at the location of the first number given and goes to, but does not include the character at the last number given.

Answer (score 0):

For substring(startIndex, endIndex), startIndex is inclusive and endIndex are exclusive. The startIndex and endIndex are very confusing.
I would understand substring(startIndex, length) to remember that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SubstringExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str="OOPs is a programming paradigm...";

        System.out.println(" Length is: " + str.length());

        System.out.println(" Substring is: " + str.substring(10, 30));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
length is: 31

Substring is: programming paradigm
```