# Remove Known Part of String Java

Tags: java, regex, string

A little help please. I want to strip-off a portion of my string which is made up of a number in Java.

eg. Have the following `Strings` - `60067` ; `600567` and `600876` and '600676600'

How do I remove `600` from each of the `strings` in Java so I remain with

`67` ; `567` and `876` and '676600'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: substring index range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570037/java-substring-index-range)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pavneet said in his comment, this works well:

```
"60067".substring(3);
```

Also, if you want to make sure it is the string `"600"` that you are removing:

```
"60067".replaceFirst("600", "");
```

Java `String`s have no `remove` method, so it's common to replace the `String` with a blank one, `""`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Many Thanks for not shooting down my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String s = "60067 ; 600567 and 600876";
s = s.replaceAll("600", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

I got

```
67 ; 567 and 876
```

Comment: [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is for regular expressions. For plain strings it is better to use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: You can use simply `replace()`(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Comment: He also probably doesn't want to replace all occurrences of the string, looking at his question, but seeing as he didn't explicitly specify, it's quite possible I could be wrong on that.