# Breaking apart a String using IndexOf and substring without using split or a loop

Tags: java, substring

Let's say I have an email address. Like: kate.daniels@somecompany.com.
And I need to break it apart without using split or loops. And that I need to use `IndexOf` in combination with substring and not using a loop (this will come later after I have a strong understanding of this first).

But looking at this email address with the understanding the email addresses are formatted like: `(firstName + "." + lastName + "@" + companyName + ".com")`

```
emailAddress = input.nextLine();
//  This is where I have issues.
firstName = emailAddress.substring(emailAddress.IndexOf(".") );

// How do I get this to be just the last name and not lastName + "@somecompany.com"
lastName = emailAddress.substring(emailAddress.IndexOf(".") + 1);

// And how do I get the company name without the ".com"
companyName = emailAddress.substring(emailAddress.IndexOf("@") + 1);
```

Thank you for any help you can provide. I can see how this would be very helpful and would like to learn.

I have looked through and I have not seen a response to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [substring index range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570037/substring-index-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do it in this scenario:

```
String emailAddress = "kate.daniels@somecompany.com";
String firstName = emailAddress.substring(0, emailAddress.indexOf('.'));
String lastName = emailAddress.substring(emailAddress.indexOf('.') + 1, emailAddress.indexOf('@'));
String companyName = emailAddress.substring(emailAddress.indexOf('@') + 1, emailAddress.lastIndexOf('.'));
System.out.println("Firstname: " + firstName + "\nLastname: " + lastName + "\nCompany: " + companyName); //Print them
```

**Output:**

```
Firstname: kate
Lastname: daniels
Company: somecompany
```

`Substring` needs two parameters to get a *range*, start and end index.  `Substring` with only a *single* parameter assumes the parameter is the beginning index and returns the rest of the `String` starting from that location.  [See the documentation here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)))

Note that the beginning index for `substring` is inclusive so for `lastName` and `companyName` I needed to put `+1` to exclude the `.` and the `@` from the result.

Another important thing to note is for the `emailAddress` I had to use `lastIndexOf(".")` because there are two periods in the `String` and this will ensure you get the final one to `substring` the correct ranges.  Normally `indexOf` returns the first occurrence.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! This is really cool. I am new to Java, I come from the database side of the world and to be able to break things up like this is wonderful.

Comment: @Martha No problem.  I know you said not to use split for the problem too, but in the future it might be useful to use something like `String [] s = emailAddress.split("[.@]");` which is much simpler and will put in the 3 names you need in the first 3 array locations!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you find the `@` first and divide the string there, you can find the `.` in either part w/o worrying about the other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that the best solution is to use `RegExp`. This is much more clear than `str.substring()`.

```
String email = "kate.daniels@somecompany.com";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<firstName>\w+)\.(?<lastName>\w+)@(?<companyName>\w+)\.\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    String firstName = matcher.group("firstName");      // kate
    String lastName = matcher.group("lastName");        // daniels
    String companyName = matcher.group("companyName");  // somecompany
}
```

---

In case you really want to use `str.substring()`, then all you need is just find a limit points and use it:

```
String email = "kate.daniels@somecompany.com";
int dotOne = email.indexOf('.');
int at = email.indexOf('@', dotOne + 1);
int dotTwo = email.indexOf('.', at + 1);

String firstName = email.substring(0, dotOne);        // kate
String lastName = email.substring(dotOne + 1, at);    // daniels
String companyName = email.substring(at + 1, dotTwo); // somecompany
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I have not yet started using RegExp, but once I do, i will come back to this. Thank you